# How to include perl modules while started from other directory?

Tags: perl

I am writing some perl script and I want to include module. Everything is okay when I am in the same directory that my script.pl is. But when I try to start my script from other directory it says it cant locate my module. My includes looks like this:

```
use Functions qw(translateWord sendHelp);
```

and the file with module is called Functions.. I tried something like this:

```
use lib '..';
```

but it failed too.. I also tried:

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
BEGIN {
    my $dir = abs_path($0);
    use lib "$dir";
}
```

but again it failed.. I also tried this:

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $dir = abs_path($0);
use lib $dir;
```

and still fail.. I am new to Perl.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting `PERL5LIB` in your `~/.bashrc` startup file..

Comment: I can't modify anything on the computer which will be used to test my script. So this is not a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way of accomplishing this is with 'use lib'. Using a lib of `..` is not ideal though, because it's relative to the current working directory when you invoke the script.

The way to accomplish this is with [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html).

E.g.

```
use FindBin;

use lib $FindBin::Bin."/../";
```

To traverse up a directory level from the 'base location' of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
BEGIN{
    unshift @INC, '/FULL/PATH/TO/DIR/OF/YOUR/MODULE';
}
```